# Android emulator window size too large and not responding to some clicks

Tags: android, maui

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise 17.8.3 with .NET Maui. I installed the current default Android emulator, which is Pixel 5 - API 34, along with Hyper-V. My Windows display resolution is 5120 x 2160.

After creating a new default project and without changing anything, it runs fine as a Windows app. However, when I use the Android emulator, the first issue I'm having is that emulator uses a window that's twice as large as it should be, in both the horizontal and vertical directions. The app loads into the upper-left quadrant of the window, with the rest of the window left empty.

After the app loads in the emulator, it looks fine (other than size), and hot changes work fine. However, the second issue is that it doesn't respond to button clicks using the mouse.

I can click-and-drag from the top of the window, so it's not completely ignoring the mouse, but somehow click events don't seem to be getting delivered to the app.

I tried increasing RAM for the emulator to 2048 MB. I also tried using the previous version of the emulator, Pixel 5 - API 33. No luck with either one.

[image]

Comment: When you're using the Android emulator, does the display exception only occur within the Maui application or do they affect the entire emulator interfaces? You can resize the emulator by moving your mouse cursor into the emulator corner, a resize icon will appear. Does resizing the emulator help restore the interface to normal?

Comment: When I resize the emulator window, the Android screen is also resized, so it continues to occupy the upper left quarter of the window. The mouse event problem only affects the Maui app. Clicking on the buttons on the right (home screen, etc) works fine. However, even from the home screen, clicks seem to be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Windows screen resolution from 5120x2160 to 2560x1080 and then restarting the emulator, fixed both problems -- mouse click events are delivered correctly, and the Android screen fills the whole window.

It's interesting that if I change the screen size back to 5120x2160 without restarting the emulator, everything continues to work fine.